# Resteasy: difference between these two paths

Tags: resteasy

Resteasy: difference between these two paths

```
@Path("/a")
public class Resource1 
{
   @GET
   @Path("/b")
   public Response get() {}
}
```

vs

```
@Path("/a")
public class Resource1 
{
   @GET
   @Path("b")
   public Response get() {}
}
```

Note that the difference is in the b.  SOF wants me to type more, so I'm typing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/Path.html):

> For an annotated method the base URI is the effective URI of the containing class. For the purposes of absolutizing a path against the base URI , a leading '/' in a path is ignored and base URIs are treated as if they ended in '/'

So in short: Both examples are effectively the same.